# Pandas Select a value in a specific column based on the index label

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

So the question actually is the following:

I create the (straight copy paste from pandas documentation) dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This creates a a DataFrame like this: (where the left-most column is acutally the index)

```
 col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

Then I want to assign my name `x` the value of the col2 and row1, which is 4. But I want to do this based on the value in col1 (cause thats the one I know). So that it looks more or less like this:

```
x = df.loc[df.col2 == df.loc[df.col1 == 2]]
```

I know this makes no sense, but maybe someone understands the issue and comes up with a hint:)
Probably this is super easy to do, but I just can wrap my head around all the .loc and .iloc possibilities at the moment

The "real" problem is to write a class which saves the coordinates (columns lat, lon) based on the provided aiport name: (and this still is kind of confusing)

```
def __init__(self, name):
        import pandas as pd
        alleDaten = pd.read_csv("airports.dat", delimiter=",", usecols=[1,6,7])
        alleDaten.columns = ["name","lat","lon"] #rename columns
        self._name = alleDaten.loc[alleDaten.name == "name"] #get name based on the provided name of the airport
        self._x = alleDaten.loc[alleDaten.name == "name", ["lat"]] # get lat based on the provided name
        self._y = alleDaten.loc[alleDaten.name == "name", ["lon"]] # get lon based on the provided name
```

Thanks a lot for any help:)!!

Comment: df.iloc[1,1] would give second column, second row value. Or if you want col2 value where col1=2, then x=df.loc[df.col1==2, 'col2'].iloc[0]

Comment: `x = df.at[1, 'col2']`

Comment: yeah, but in case you just know the value for one column, but want to assign the variable the value of another column of the same row:/ 
Hope it makes sense...

Comment: awesome, I needed to long typing my reponse! I'll try these variations out:) 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick for you (to get only value of filtered pandas):

```py
x = df.loc[df.col1 == 2, "col2"]
print(x.to_list()[0])
```

Output:

```py
4

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Comment: Any idea of how not to return a DataFrame-Object and instead an float?
casting it just an float seems not to work

Comment: Yup, as per the above - ```x.to_list()[0]```. Then you'll get back just the first value of the returned result.

Comment: thanks:) Now it worked

Answer (score 0):

`x = df.iloc[1, 1]`
The numbering system starts at 0, so [1, 1] will select the second row and second column.